# Is this tree behavior possible in a C# web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, treeview, treelist

I'm writing a C# 4.0 web app and I need a tree type control.  I rarely use tree controls. I have been trying out the Telerik RadTreeView and TreeList but so far, nothing close to what I want.

What I need is a tree control that displays values from a header/detail table set.  The tree should consist of a set of root nodes with only one child level.  Each node, root or child needs to have a display label and **two** check boxes *(and presumably some hidden fields to keep track of a multi-part database key)*.  I want to be able to populate the tree **once** on load and then be able to expand and contract nodes without post back and without losing whatever changes the user might make to any of the check boxes.  I then want to hit a submit button and process the current settings in server-side code.

Is this even possible?  What would be the optimum way to implement this?

Comment: IMHO, The best was to do this would be to use the client side API of those tools you already have.

Comment: maybe this might help http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/160773/Expandable-Rows-in-GridView

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `TreeView` control if you only have one level of child elements to account for. I would suggest using a flexible control like the `DataList`, `ListView`, or `Repeater` to handle the rendering, and adding some supporting jQuery or JavaScript to expand/collapse your nodes on the client.